# TypeError: train_test_split() got multiple values for argument 'test_size' only when I write it in a function

Tags: python, dataframe, classification, xgboost

For a dataframe `df_content` that looks like this:

```
rated_object     feature_1    feature_2    feature_n    rating
o1               2.02         0            90.40        0
o2               3.70         1            NaN          1
o3               3.45         0            70.50        1
o4               7.90         1            40.30        0
...
```

I wrote the following function:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd

def predict_cn(df, rated_object):
    is_target = (df['rated_object'] == rated_object)
    target = df[is_target].iloc[0]
    cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
    df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
    X = df.drop('rating', axis=1)  
    y = df['rating'] 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
    model = XGBClassifier() 
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    prediction=model.predict(target['rated_object'], verbose=False)
    return prediction
```

But giving an input like `predict_cn(df_content, 'o3')` gives me the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-08dcbb77df37> in <module>
----> 1 predict_cn(df_content, 'o3')

<ipython-input-9-18667675e17b> in predict_cn(df, rated_object)
      6     X = df.drop('rating', axis=1)
      7     y = df['rating']
----> 8     X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
      9     model = XGBClassifier()
     10     model.fit(X_train, y_train)

TypeError: train_test_split() got multiple values for argument 'test_size'
```

I find it strange because when I run such a model separately for this whole dataframe it works fine and this is also the syntax from the documentation. I also don't know if the rest of my code is correct if I want to input a `rated_object` and obtain its predicted `rating`.

EDIT: following @Antoine Dubuis suggestions, I tried to create a copy of the dataframe. Below I will post the new function and a small mock dataframe, but the error persists:

```
from numpy import nan
data_mock = [['q1', 10.93, 20, 1, 0], ['q2', nan, 12, 0, 1], ['q3', 14.34, 30, 0, 1], ['q4', 12.93, 20, 0, 1], ['q5', nan, 62, 1, 0], ['q6', 14.34, 60, 0, 0], ['q7', 16.93, 28, 1, 1], ['q8', nan, 12, 1, 1], ['q9', 10.34, 50, 0, 0], ['q10', 10.93, 20, 0, 0], ['q11', nan, 57, 1, 1], ['q12', 89.34, 30, 0, 0]]
df_mock = pd.DataFrame(data_mock, columns = ['rated_object', 'feature_1', 'feature_2', 'feature_n', 'rating'])
def predict_cn(df, rated_object):
    df_copy=df.copy()
    is_target = (df_copy['rated_object'] == rated_object)
    target = df_copy[is_target].iloc[0]
    cols_to_drop = ['rated_object'] 
    df_copy.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
    X = df_copy.drop('rating', axis=1)  
    y = df_copy['rating']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
    model = XGBClassifier() 
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test) 
    prediction=model.predict(target['questionId'], verbose=False)
    return prediction
```

Answer (score 1):

You should verify the variable `X` and `y`. There must be an error with your `y` array as it is not interpreted as a `pd.Series` but as a numerical value.

As it is a numerical value, it is interpreted as the positional argument `train_size` instead of the `arrays` parameter that must be splitted.

Comment: Indeed, I printed y and I get Name: rating, Length: 2895, dtype: int64. I wrote it instead as `y = pd.DataFrame(df_content['rating'])`, but I still get the error.

Comment: In my opition, you should ensure that your function is idempotent. Meaning that you can it does not modify external data. I would perform a `df.copy()` at first to ensure that you are not modifying the original dataframe. This might be the issue. If your dataframe has multiple rows, your code should work as is from my point of view.

Comment: I did define `df2=df.copy()`, I tried it at the beginning and it didn't work and then before dropping the columns and it didn't work. Where in the code should I perform the copy? I also tried writing `y = df['rating'].values` so that `y` is an array and it didn't work.

Comment: I think I was wrong in my first comment, because if I print y it is indeed a series, and it's the same as if when I print it separately, running the model normally and not written as a function. I think you are right about it modifying my data, but I don't know where to place the copy.

Comment: you should put it at the beginning of the function to ensure that nothing change your original `DataFrame`.

Comment: I posted a mock dataframe and the new function to play around with, and the error persists, I don't see where the mistake is. I would be so grateful if you could take a look, because I feel like it is such a trivial thing but it still doesn't work.